# How to remove a first character of that particular sentences from a list of output

Tags: text-processing, awk, regular-expression

```
grep /var/log /etc/rsyslog.conf | awk '{print $2}'
```

Output:

```
/var/log/messages
/var/log/secure
-/var/log/maillog
/var/log/cron
-/var/log/spooler
/var/log/boot.log
```

I want the result to be:

```
/var/log/messages
/var/log/secure
/var/log/maillog
/var/log/cron
/var/log/spooler
/var/log/boot.log
```

I need to remove the `-`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep /var/log /etc/rsyslog.conf | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/^-//'
```

`sed` will look for the start of a line `s/^` followed by a hyphen `-` and replace it with an empty string `//`.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to expand the command to remove the `-` hyphen character:

```
grep /var/log /etc/rsyslog.conf | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/^-//g'

grep /var/log /etc/rsyslog.conf | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d '-'
```

Or using `awk`:

```
grep /var/log /etc/rsyslog.conf | awk '{sub("-","",$2);print $2}'
```

Comment: That would remove the first occurrence of a hyphen on the line (so those lines that contain a hyphen, not at the beginning of the line, will have it removed `/var/log/my-log` would become `/var/log/mylog`). You can tie the hyphen to the beginning of the line with a carat `^`.

Comment: Yes, Drav is right.  But what should I use instead of ^ , if I want to use "tr -d"? I tried use ^, but it also remove the hyphen from any contains of hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

**Easy solution**

You tagged your question linux, so I presume you are using GNU grep. Then it would be easiest to just modify your `grep` call to output only the text you want:

```
grep -o '/var/log/.*' /etc/rsyslog.conf
```

The `-o` option results in `grep` printing only the matching part, not the whole line. For this, I added the `/.*` to the pattern. This works, as the path is the last component in the line.

---

**Modifications**

If there was something following the path that you do *not* want to get printed, the regexp and the `grep` call would look a bit different:

```
egrep -o '/var/log/\S*' /etc/rsyslog.conf
```

This would include any sequence of non-whitespace (`\S`) characters after the `/var/log/`. Since `\S` belongs to extended regular expressions, the call changed to `egrep` instead of `grep`. (You could also use `grep -E` for that.)

If you also want to **sort** the resulting list, and probably **eliminate duplicates,** the result could be piped into `sort`:

```
egrep -o '/var/log/\S*' /etc/rsyslog.conf | sort -u
```

The `-u` stands for "unique", so duplicates are removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the leading dash `-` from field 2 using the `sub()` function of `awk`:

```
grep /var/log /etc/rsyslog.conf | awk '{ sub(/^-/, "", $2); print $2 }'
```

If you need to remove *all* dashes from the beginning of field 2:

```
grep /var/log /etc/rsyslog.conf | awk '{ sub(/^-*/, "", $2); print $2 }'
```

Or eliminate `grep` and search for the pattern with `awk`:

```
awk '/\/var\/log/ { sub(/^-*/, "", $2); print $2 }' /etc/rsyslog.conf
```